# TestNG's attribute dependsOnMethods doesn't support hierachy?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, testng

I have 3 test methods, let's call `method1`, `method2` and `method3`. `Method1` can be executed alone. But `method2` depends on `method1`, it means, `method1` prepares the workflow for `method2` to continue. And `method3` depends on `method1` and `method2` in this regard.

Of course I can combine all 3 in one test method and it worked. But since I use TestNG, and I find out about `dependsOnMethods`, so I would like to try it. That's why i break down my test into 3 methods like this:

```
@Test
public void method1() {
    // do test steps        
}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = {"method1"})
public void method2() {
    // do test steps
}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = {"method2"})
public void method3() {
    // do test steps
}
```

And `method1` is executed successfully. When I execute `method2`, then `method1` is executed first and then `method2`. This is what I want.

That's why I suppose that, if I execute `method3`, then `method2` will be executed, and since `method2` depends on `method1`, then `method1` should be executed first, so in this order: `method1 -> method2 -> method3`. But it doesn't work obviously. I get this `TestNGException`:

```
method2() is depending on method1(), which is not annotated with @Test or not included
```

After that I try this:

```
@Test(dependsOnMethods = {"method1" , "method2"})
public void method3() {
    // do test steps
}
```

Actually, method1 is called first, because I see web browser is opened with the url, but that's it, it doesn't go further, it stops there, and I get this log:

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
[1521042814,797][SEVERE]: Unable to retrieve document state disconnected: received Inspector.detached event

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from disconnected: received Inspector.detached event
```

Can anyone suggest me an explanation and a solution. My tests run on Chrome. Thank you for reading.

Comment: It's generally a good idea to [avoid ordering of the tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) and minimize any dependency between them. Something like the [PageObject Pattern](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html) might be useful where you have a common method that encapsulates the Navigation to Method3 by encapsulating Method2's Navigate and Method2's Navigate by encapsulating Navigate for Method 1. Although it might be overkill and you'll want to keep in mind DRY and SOLID Principles.

Comment: There's a closed issue on the [git repo](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1323) that hints at how you can handle shared state between tests.

Comment: @lloyd Thanks. I also tried with 'priority', and it also worked. But as you said, I want to avoid ordering of tests, that's why I am trying with dependsOnMethods. I also checked the issue you suggested, it is not quite the same as mine, unfortunately :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run your test case in that particular order(`method1->method2->method3`), please try out the below solutions.

> Approach1

```
public class TestOrder {


    @Test
    public void method1() {
        System.out.println("method1");        
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = {"method1"})
    public void method2() {
        System.out.println("method2");
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = {"method2"})
    public void method3() {
        System.out.println("method3");
    }

}
```

and your `testng.xml` file structure is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" preserve-order="true">
    <test thread-count="1" name="Test">
        <classes>
            <class name="grid.TestOrder"/>
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

and i am getting the output like this.

```
method1
method2
method3

===============================================
Suite
Total tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

> Approach2

```
public class TestOrder {


    @Test
    public void method1() {
        System.out.println("method1");        
    }

    @Test
    public void method2() {
        System.out.println("method2");
    }

    @Test
    public void method3() {
        System.out.println("method3");
    }
}
```

Here you have to change something in your `testng.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" preserve-order="true">
    <test thread-count="1" name="Test">
        <classes>
            <class name="grid.TestOrder">
                <methods>
                    <include name="method1" />
                    <include name="method2" />
                    <include name="method3" />
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

This time also, i am getting the same output

```
method1
method2
method3

===============================================
Suite
Total tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

> method2() is depending on method1(), which is not annotated with @Test
>   or not included

Because you are trying running `method2` alone without giving details of dependent method.

Probably, you designed your `xml` file like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" preserve-order="true">
    <test thread-count="1" name="Test">
        <classes>
            <class name="grid.TestOrder">
                <methods>
                    <include name="method2" />
                    <include name="method3" />
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

You should include, either all the methods or class name in `<classes>` tag. You can checkout [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/testng-users/ciy1C9Bt9FY) for more info.

> `From Cedric Beust's answer(link source):` " The `<classes>` tag is the list of classes and methods
>   that TestNG should look at before it starts resolving things, such as
>   which groups to run, what the dependencies are, etc... So the first thing  to do is to include the entire class in your testng.xml "

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried it with testng.xml and it worked. What I meant in my question, maybe i was not clear, that I tried to run it within IntelliJ IDE, like, right click on the @Test annotation and click run. And it happens as I described in my question. Means, right click and run on `method1` and `method2` works, but `method3` throws exception. I guess, it's not supposed to run within IntelliJ this way. Do you have any idea. Thanks